# Switching a tensor and a partial derivative

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

Pretty simple stuff again, but I was wondering if:

$T_{\mu\nu}\partial_{\alpha}=\partial_{\alpha}T_{\mu\nu}$, where T is just some tensor. I mean I'm guessing that at least $T_{\mu\nu}\partial_{\mu}=\partial_{\mu}T_{\mu\nu}$ isn't true.

If the first equation isn't true, how would one manipulate $T_{\mu\nu}\partial_{\alpha}$ to get partial derivative in front of the tensor or is that even reasonably possible?

Comment: In full generality, this is not "even reasonably possible". Consider on $\Bbb R^2$ the tensor $T = (x+y)\mathrm{id}$.

Comment: Note that the right hand side is a number while the left hand side is an operator.

Comment: @lcv Why do you say the right-hand side is a number? It's still an operator (where the derivative acts by the product rule).